# Why last port number isn't being appended to list?

Tags: python

I'm facing a bizarre problem when adding port numbers passed as arguments:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog '+'-H <target host> -p <target port>')

parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
options, args = parser.parse_args()
tgtHost = options.tgtHost
p, tgtPorts = '', []
for i,char in enumerate(options.tgtPort):
    if char != ',':
        p += char
    elif i == len(options.tgtPort)-1:
        tgtPorts.append(p)
        p = ''
    else:
        tgtPorts.append(p)
        p = ''
    print(p)

print(tgtPorts)
```

this outputs:

```
8
80

4
44
443

4
44
445            # 445 NOT BEING APPENDED. WHY ???
['80', '443']
```

My question is why the last port number won't get appended to the list ?

Comment: Why not use `str.split`?

Comment: Presumably, because `char != ','`....

Comment: Have you considered using `tgtPorts.split(',')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re checking if `char != ','` before checking if `i == len(options.tgtPort) - 1`. The latter is an `elif`, so when `char != ','` is true it won’t run.

[Splitting is a built-in string operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), though, so there’s no need to go through any of this:

```
tgtPorts = options.tgtPort.split(',')
```

Comment: I used the `split()` function before I went for this rather cumbersome "solution" but didn't work for me some reason. Hence I went for `for` loop. This time around the `split()` function worked nicely. Thanks a lot ! I can progress now.